# Uploading images to IMGUR using Volley returns TimeoutError

Tags: android, android-volley, imgur

I am trying to upload an image to my Imgur account using `Volley` `StringRequest`. I am not sure how to handle the response so what happens is it keeps re uploading since it hasnt received a response from Imgur. The image ends up being uploaded a couple of times until the `TimeoutError` is thrown. How can I ensure this does not happen as I cannot detect the response being returned from the Imgur server?
Here is the method I am using to upload the image after converting it to Base64:

```
 public void uploadImage(View view) {
    Log.i(TAG,"start upload");
    StringRequest uploadRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConst.IMGUR_ADD_IMG, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "finished image upload");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
            Log.e(TAG,"finish/error upload");
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(AppConst.IMGUR_TAG_IMAGE, encodeImage(selectedImg));
            params.put(AppConst.IMGUR_TAG_TITLE, "title");
            params.put(AppConst.IMGUR_TAG_NAME, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            return params;
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(uploadRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the DefaultRetryPolicy on the Request to have a larger expiration time frame, since uploading an image can take a bit.  Also, for the double upload, make sure to have max_retries set to 0.

`new DefaultRetryPolicy(LONGER_TIMEOUT, 0, 0);`

Comment: Setting retry to zero seems to be uploading the image once as required but TimeOut and SSL errors are still showing up